# Stepping through a video file with reveal.js

Tags: javascript, reveal.js

#### Problem and question

In a reveal.js presentation, I want to include a long video file. I want to have the playblack stop at certain positions, so that I have time to explain to the audience what they’re seeing. Then, I want to have the playback continue when I click. How can I do this?

#### Unsuccessful attempts so far

My attempts are as follows. I split the video file into parts `1.webm`, `2.webm`, `3.webm` and so on, such that each part ends where I want to have a break. My idea then is to

1. Override the keydown event of Reveal.js so that it doesn’t go to the next slide, but instead executes my Javascript. How can I do something like this?

   ```
   <div class="slides">
       <section class="video-stepper">
           <video>
               <source data-src="1.webm" type="video/webm" />
           </video>
       </section>
   </div>

   <script>
       $(function() {
           // How can I do this?
           Reveal.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
               if ($(event.currentSlide).hasClass('video-stepper')) {
                   event.preventDefault();
                   // change 'src' of the video element and start the playback.
               }
           });
       });
   </script>
   ```
2. Use fragments and autoplay the video when it is shown:

   ```
   <div class="slides">
       <section class="video-stepper">
           <video class="fragment current-visible video-step">
               <source data-src="1.webm" type="video/webm" />
           </video>
           <video class="fragment current-visible video-step">
               <source data-src="2.webm" type="video/webm" />
           </video>
           <video class="fragment current-visible video-step">
               <source data-src="3.webm" type="video/webm" />
           </video>
       </section>
   </div>

   <script>
       $(function() {
           Reveal.addEventListener('fragmentshown', function(event) {
               if ($(event.fragment).hasClass('video-step')) {
                   event.fragment.play();
               }
           });
       });
   </script>
   ```

   And some CSS taken from the question [Hide reveal.js fragments after their appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34111675/1231686), so that the fragments stack on top of each other:

   ```
   .fragment.current-visible.visible:not(.current-fragment) {
       display: none;
       height:0px;
       line-height: 0px;
       font-size: 0px;
   }
   ```

   However, this comes with some fading in and out, which looks bad. How can I avoid the fading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When entering the video slide, you can basically disable reveal.js by calling `Reveal.disableEventListeners()`, then bind your own logic to the keydown event until you’ve stepped through all videos, before enabling reveal.js again with `Reveal.addEventListeners()`.

Some additional effort is required to avoid flickering when transitioning to the next video. You can add a new `<video>` element with the new video, place it on top of the current `<video>` with the help of CSS `z-index`, play the new video, then remove the old.

#### HTML

```
<section class="video-stepper">
    <!-- Unlike the other <video> element, this one is not absolutely 
         positioned. We hide it with CSS, but use it to reserve space
         on the slide and compute the optimal width and height. -->
    <video class="placeholder stretch">
        <source src="1.webm">
    </video>

    <video class="video-step" data-sources='["1.webm","2.webm","3.webm"]'></video>
</section>
```

#### CSS

```
.video-stepper {
    position: relative;
}

video.video-step {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

video.video-step.front {
    z-index: 10;
}

video.placeholder {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

#### Javascript

This is a bit lengthy, but works as desired.

```
Reveal.addEventListener('slidechanged', function(event) {
    if ($(event.currentSlide).hasClass('video-stepper')) {
        // When we enter a slide with a step-by-step video, we stop reveal.js
        //  from doing anything. Below, we define our own keystroke handler.
        Reveal.removeEventListeners();

        // Set the width and height of the video so that it fills the slide.
        var stretcher = $(event.currentSlide).find('video.placeholder').get(0);
        var video = $(event.currentSlide).find('video.video-step').get(0);
        video.setAttribute('width', stretcher.getAttribute('width'));
        video.setAttribute('height', stretcher.getAttribute('height'));

        // Convert the data-sources attribute to an array of strings. We will
        // iterate through the array with current_video_index.
        var sources = JSON.parse(video.getAttribute('data-sources'));
        var current_video_index = 0;

        // Add a <source> element to the video and set the 'src' to
        // the first video.
        var source = document.createElement('source');
        source.setAttribute('src', sources[0]);
        video.appendChild(source);

        document.addEventListener('keydown', function step_through_videos(event) {
            if (event.which == 39) {
                // right arrow key: show next video

                // For the next video, create a new <video> element
                // and place it on top of the old <video> element.
                // Then load and play the new. This avoids flickering.
                var new_video = $(video).clone().get(0);
                var new_video_source = $(new_video).children('source').get(0);
                new_video_source.src = sources[current_video_index];
                new_video.load();
                $(new_video).addClass('front video-step');
                $(new_video).insertAfter(video);
                new_video.play();

                // Wait a little before removing the old video.
                new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500)).then(function() {
                    video.remove();
                    video = new_video;
                    $(video).removeClass('front');
                });

                current_video_index = current_video_index + 1;

                event.preventDefault();
            } else if (event.which == 37) {
                // left arrow key: return the counter to previous video
                current_video_index = current_video_index - 1;

                event.preventDefault();
            }

            if (0 > current_video_index || current_video_index >= sources.length) {
                // Reinstall reveal.js handlers.

                document.removeEventListener('keydown', step_through_videos, true);
                Reveal.addEventListeners();
                console.log('Added reveal.js event listeners.');
            }
        }, true);
    }
});
```